# Upload only one table using heroku pg:transfer instead of whole database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm able to push my database from my local machine to my heroku app with pg:transfer like this:

`heroku pg:transfer --from postgres://localhost/idx_map_development --to aqua`

But I don't want to upload the whole database, I only want to upload the properties table, is this possible using pg:transfer? If so how would the above line look?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

did it with pg_dump:

`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U username -t properties idx_map_development > properties.dump`

The file called properties.dump gets only the data for the properties table and I upload the file to an Amazon S3 bucket and can then push it to heroku with this:

`heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/properties.dump'`

The other tables on my heroku db are unaffected. You don't need to specify the properties table in the `pgbackups:restore` command.

Comment: Just a warning that I'm not sure this works anymore. When I try it, it wipes out the whole db. From the heroku docs:
_Unlike with the previous pgbackups commands, you cannot restore a partial backup into an existing database. When you run pg:backups restore, all data is deleted from the target database before restoring the backup._

[heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#restoring-backups)

Comment: Can you update this answer to reflect the new pg:backups behavior referenced in the above comment?

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned by @eugjill, this doesn't work anymore. So first you do the dump, as described by @railsy:

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U username -t properties idx_map_development > properties.dump
```

Then instead of using pgbackups, use the pg_restore:

```
PGPASSWORD=<PASSWORD> pg_restore --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -h <HOST> -U <USER> -d <DATABASE> -p <PORT> properties.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

The pg_dump above worked for me as well; though I needed all of the options described.

I had two tables; a user table and a transactions table.

```
pg_dump -t transactions db/development > transactions_clobber.bak
```

When I restored from this; the user table was lost.

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -t transactions db/development > transactions_works.bak
```

works as advertised.